# h:selectOneMenu render other components when default item selected?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

Below you can check `<h:selectOnemenu/>` I have added `valueChangeListener` attribute and `render="Component1,Component2"` some other component from same page

```
     <h:selectOneMenu required="true" id="ETState" requiredMessage="Required Message" value="#{bean.listofRecords}" valueChangeListener="#{bean.changeListner}'>
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Item" noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{eTManagedBean.fetchStates()}" var="state" itemLabel="#{state.value}" itemValue="#{state.stateId}" />
     <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" immediate="true" execute="@this" render="Component1,Component2"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

Now if some item is selected at that time event will fire and and component also render but suppose now user select default value from SelectOneMenu.

Default value means  `<f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Item" noSelectionOption="true" />`  Now in this case its possible to render again the other components `Component1` and `Component2` ?

Comment: In other words, you mean to say that `<a4j:ajax>` is not fired when default option is selected, or that it simply does not execute the `render`? Nonetheless, the `noSelectionOption` is misunderstood here. You're not utilizing the `hideNoSelectionOption`. Get rid of it and just use `itemValue="#{null}"`.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks I got your point.